# Cannot import Android package "com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.*"

Tags: android, import, adview, google-mobile-ads

This is for a simple Android app as my first step to test banner ads in an Android app.

I followed examples, guidelines, and arrived at the need for these import lines in MainActivity.java:

```
// these are needed for advertising:
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
```

But the builder cannot resolve the last two lines:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
```

Why???

I use AndroidX 1.0.0 library (after migrating from Support Library 28.0.0).

The dependencies in build.gradle of the app package are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0' // added by Henrik to access AdView
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
}
```

I have of course added the layout item AdView into  activity_main.xml.

I have downloaded Google Play services SDK - it did not help (no change)
I have downloaded Google Repository  - it did not help (no change)

What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The version you are using is way too old. Use the latest and compatible version. Its already there in [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start).

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'
```

Comment: Thank you, this upgrade to play-services-ads:19.6.0 helped and now the two import statements are OK, buildable.